# Using multiple values for one parameter in a command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to code a quiz bot in discord, and right now I want to find a way to have my bot pull a random question from specific parameters. I'm not so sure this was the right way to phrase it, but here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def ask1(ctx , q):
    quiz_data = {
        'question1' : (["1" , "one"] , "one") , 
        'question2' : (["2" , "two"] , "two") , 
    }

    questionp1 = random.choice(list(quiz_data.keys()))
    answersp1 , hintp1 = quiz_data[questionp1]

    quiz_data1 = {
        'question3' : (["3" , "three"] , "three") , 
        'question4' : (["4" , "four"] , "four")
    }

    questionp2 = random.choice(list(quiz_data1.keys()))
    answersp2 , hintp2 = quiz_data1[questionp2]

    global var
    if var == 0:
        var = 1
        if q == "1":
            await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await ctx.send(questionp1)

            def check_sender(msg):
                return msg.channel == ctx.channel
            def check_answer(msg):
                return any(answer in msg.content.lower() for answer in answersp1)

            try:
                async with timeout(10):
                    while var == 1:
                        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
                        if check_answer(msg):
                            await ctx.send("Well done.")
                            var = 0                     
                            break
                        else:
                            print(msg.content)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                if var != 1:
                    var = 0
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f"What is the answer to this question? hint: {hintp1}")
                    await ctx.send(questionp1)

                    try:
                        async with timeout(5):
                            while var == 1:
                                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
                                if check_answer(msg):
                                    await ctx.send("Well done.")
                                    var = 0
                                    break
                                else:
                                    print(msg.content)
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await ctx.send("No one got it right.")
                        var = 0
        elif q == "2":
            await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await ctx.send(questionp2)

            def check_sender(msg):
                return msg.channel == ctx.channel
            def check_answer(msg):
                return any(answer in msg.content.lower() for answer in answersp2)

            try:
                async with timeout(10):
                    while var == 1:
                        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
                        if check_answer(msg):
                            await ctx.send("Well done.")
                            var = 0                     
                            break
                        else:
                            print(msg.content)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                if var != 1:
                    var = 0
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f"What is the answer to this question? hint: {hintp2}")
                    await ctx.send(questionp2)

                    try:
                        async with timeout(5):
                            while var == 1:
                                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
                                if check_answer(msg):
                                    await ctx.send("Well done.")
                                    var = 0
                                    break
                                else:
                                    print(msg.content)
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await ctx.send("No one got it right.")
                        var = 0
    else:
        await ctx.send("A round has already begun.")
```

This is the concept that I'm currently using. The command `$ask1 1` and `$ask1 2` are working fine, but I want the user to have a choice to put `$ask1 q:1,2` or something like that, which the bot then pulls a question from either the first quizdata set or the second. Note that this whole code is working well and is executed without any errors. I've been racking my brain for a few days and  I think to do this I should be using keyword args instead of positional args, but I'm not entirely sure nor do I know how to apply the concept of kwargs properly in this situation. The `var`s are necessary for a different command btw, a stop command, so you don't have to pay attention to it.

Sorry if this is hard to understand, I'll be willing to answer any questions to make this more clear. Any answer wil be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use random lib,here is the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html. What I was thinking you could at first generate random number between 1 and 2 if the random number is 1 you would go to quiz data if 2 to quiz data2 and then generate another random number between 1 and to and that would indicate which question from this quiz data would be used

Comment: Thanks @SimonTheAnt, but i'm not sure if we're on the same page here. I think I understand what you're saying, but I don't see how a user will be able to use `$ask1 q:1,2` or the like since your answer only tackles the part of random choices in the data. I'm not sure if I'm the one that's mistaken but I think I've already got that concept down in my code. Thanks for your answer though I appreciate it~